# understanding the result of this bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash -x

for line in `tail /home/user/line`

 do
      echo $line
 done
```

but dont know why it echos all words instead of each line
below is output

```
++ tail /home/user/line
+ for line in '`tail /home/user/line`'
+ echo Linux
Linux
+ for line in '`tail /home/user/line`'
+ echo is
is
+ for line in '`tail /home/user/line`'
+ echo a
a
+ for line in '`tail /home/user/line`'
+ echo crappy
crappy
+ for line in '`tail /home/user/line`'
+ echo OS
OS
+ for line in '`tail /home/user/line`'
+ echo Do
Do
+ for line in '`tail /home/user/line`'
+ echo you
you
+ for line in '`tail /home/user/line`'
+ echo 'agree?'
agree?
+ for line in '`tail /home/user/line`'
+ echo Unix
Unix
+ for line in '`tail /home/user/line`'
+ echo is
is
+ for line in '`tail /home/user/line`'
+ echo much
much
+ for line in '`tail /home/user/line`'
+ echo better
better
+ for line in '`tail /home/user/line`'
+ echo Or
Or
+ for line in '`tail /home/user/line`'
+ echo maybe
maybe
+ for line in '`tail /home/user/line`'
+ echo Solaris
Solaris
+ for line in '`tail /home/user/line`'
+ echo 'OS?'
OS?
+ for line in '`tail /home/user/line`'
+ echo Linux
Linux
+ for line in '`tail /home/user/line`'
+ echo Linux
Linux
+ for line in '`tail /home/user/line`'
+ echo 'Linux!'
Linux!
```

here is the text file

```
Linux is a crappy OS

Do you agree?

Unix is much better
Or maybe Solaris OS?
Linux Linux Linux!
```

Any idea why its not not echoing line by line?
Thanks

Comment: See eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642191/read-line-by-line-in-bash-script

Answer (score 1):

if you want to print the lines, you need to use `while read line` using `while read` you will read line by line, for example:

```
while read line;do echo $line ;done < /etc/passwd
```

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: @granttailor i edited my answer.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you pass data to a for loop, it considers both spaces and returns as a break in the input. It's so you can do stuff like: for i in \`pidof fooprocess\` ; do kill -9 $i ; done     or    for field in \`cat blah.csv | cut -d , -f 2-4 | sed 's/,/\ /g' \` ; echo something something $field ; done